# Yum or Reposync: How can I slowly remove a repository without unintended dependency issues?

Tags: centos, rhel, yum, repository

I have used reposync to create and maintain local copies of two repositories, remi and remi-test. These are repositories maintained by Remi Collet. On several systems in an internal LAN, I added both repos and have used them. So there are, at any given time, files from both repos installed on my systems. (My systems are a mix of the latest version of RHEL/CentOS 5 and 6).

Now I want to remove, over time, all of the files which are installed from the remi-test repo and only use files from the remi repo.

If I use:

```
# reposync -d -r remi-test
```

that will delete any files from my local copy that are also deleted from the remi-test repository, and then will download the new files into my local copy.

How would I begin to only `yum update` from remi, and not remi-test, without simply uninstalling (via `yum erase`) all remi-test files? What I'm trying to avoid is sudden dependency errors due to uninstalling newer files (which would be in remi-test, but not yet remi).

Is this a reposync solvable 'problem', or a yum one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Easiest way to do that would be to just stop using the remi-test repository as a source and remove, or if you want to be safer -- disable it by editing the `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi-test.repo` file and changing `enabled=1` to `enabled=0`

You could still force yum to use the repo via command line, but it would no longer be used for generic updates. Over time the packages would be replaced by the ones in remi.